# Fully-Firstable Anagram Sets

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers, anagram

Okay, first let's define some terminology:

- Anagram - Oh come on, how are you on Puzzling.SE if you don't know this one?
- Anagram Set - a list of words that are all anagrams of eachother, e.g.:

  - ACTS
  - CAST
  - CATS
  - SCAT
- Fully-Firstable - An anagram set where each of the letters can be found at the beginning of at least one of the words.  The previous example would not qualify because there is no word starting with 'T'.  One example would be:

  - OPTS
  - POST or POTS
  - SPOT or STOP
  - TOPS

I have been able to find a relatively small number of these.  One optional rule I will allow to increase the chances of finding more is that if a set contains more than one of the same letter, you only need to have one word which starts with that letter, e.g. the set:

- EEL
- LEE

Only needs 2 words to qualify since there are only 2 unique letters.

I can easily find a number of 3- and 4-letter sets, but I am aware of only two 5-letter sets with this property, one of which uses the letter-doubling rule and one which does not.  Can you find them?  Are there more?  Are there any with 6 or more letters?

Oh, let's disallow some things: No proper nouns or acronyms (unless these acronyms have since become commonly used as standard words such as "laser" or "scuba"), no splitting the letters into 2 or more words, stick to English please - my examples are relatively common words, but if you come up with any that use questionable or archaic words you might want to back them up with a reputable dictionary link.  Also, screams, laughs, or other sound effects are not words.  I'm looking at you, "AAAAAA" or "AHAHAH / HAHAHA".  These are trivial to come up with and thus disqualified.

**Scoring**

Since the original intended answers have both been found, the search is on for longer sets!  The set with the most letters will take the checkmark - in the event of a tie, the set that relies the least on letter-doubling will win.

Comment: ahh my brain read it as "Fistable" and I was so confused for a couple moments.

Comment: Yeah, couldn't think of a better word for it, so made my own...

Comment: @Sensoray mhmm, me too xD

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Didn't know this stack community existed, found it by chance when this thread came up in my feed, and I do love puzzles so I'm joining. Taking a shot at this one with this entry, one of my words is considered colloquial or obsolete though.

> Enters
>  Ernest (For the second E - [Obsolete variant of Earnest](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ernest#Middle_English))
>  Nester
>  Resent
>  Streen / Strene ([Obsolete variant of Strain](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Strene))
>  Tenser

Comment: nice first answer, welcome here! +1 in respect :)

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! You formatted it mostly right, just need to put 4 spaces at the end of each line to make the new one appear on a new line.

Comment: Thanks @Sensoray - I was wondering what I was doing wrong there with the spoiler format, never used it before.

Comment: Great job! It's nice have have great new users!

Comment: @Sensoray TWO spaces, not four. :)  Welcome tremor and congrats on the checkmark!

Comment: @Rubio WHAAAAT!?! my mind is blown. I swore it was 4....is there another formatting thing that requires 4 spaces? bc I swear I wasn't doing 4 spaces for no reason....

Comment: @Sensoray 4 spaces is common for code-blocks in wiki markup - is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: Thanks all for the warm welcome, I also edited my answer to add another "e" word, instead of doubling, since there are two e's in my answer, I figured I ought to have two "e" words.

Comment: (is that new word, well, actually a word? It's a *name*, but ...)

Comment: @Rubio - another obsolete variant, added citation per the OPs rules. Thanks for pointing it out though, because I thought it was the actual spelling,

Answer (score 11):

I found the same one as @Omega Krypton did (first time I got answer sniped, darn!), but I also found a possible letter doubling solution:

> **ESTER** 
>  **RESET** 
>  **STEER** 
>  **TREES**

and a couple of questionable ones:

> **EWERS** 
>  **RESEW** 
>  **SEWER** 
>  **WERES** (fantasy term for people who can transform into other beings; doesn’t appear in OED, Merriam-Webster, or Dictionary.com unfortunately) 
>  
>  **EASTS** 
>  **SEATS** 
>  **ASSET** 
>  **TASES** (uses a taser on someone; doesn’t appear in OED but does on [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tase) and [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tase))

Comment: For weres: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weres?

Comment: Your first one is my intended letter-doubling solution.  (It could also include rot13(GREFR)).  Your other ones are indeed questionable, but you can have the checkmark - @OmegaKrypton has the other answer I was looking for, but found it with a computer, so this one wins for now - unless somebody can find a 6+ set...

Comment: Thanks so much for your inspiration for the 6+ set!

Comment: and sorry for taking away your check, a +1 for you in respect!

Answer (score 9):

**6 words (with doubling) (self-generated)** (thanks @PiIsNot3 for inspiration)

> ```
> esters
> resets
> steers
> treses
> ```

**5 words (Confession: with computer)**

> ```
> emits
> mites
> items
> times
> smite
> ```

Comment: This is one of the sets I was looking for.  @PilsNot3 found the other one, afraid I'll have to give them the checkmark since you used a computer, but take a +1 anyhow.

Comment: Hmm, a bit obscure on that last one, but I guess I can allow it - in the interests of tie-breaking though, those requiring the fewest letter-doublings will take precedence.  (e.g. if someone finds a 6-letter with only 1 or no doubles, it would beat this one.  A 7-letter or more would beat either, etc.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman please give the check to tremor with one less dupe, thanks:)

Answer (score 7):

I think I've found another one

> argon 
>  groan 
>  [nagor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nagor) 
>  organ 
>  rogan (as in [rogan josh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogan_josh))

Comment: I can accept your 3rd word, but the 5th one I'm pretty sure is a proper noun...

Answer (score 7):

Shamelessly taken from @Tom’s question and @Soltius’ answer is this one (did you collaborate)??

> [Aretes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arete) 
>  Eaters 
>  
>  Reseat 
>  Seater 
>  
>  Teaser

Comment: I don't think I've seen the question you're referring to, so no, no collaboration.  I feel like your first word might be considered either a proper noun or a foreign word?  Seems to be consistently either capitalized or italicized in that article...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's in SOWPODS and other Scrabble dictionaries, but seems to be there for its other meaning of mountain ridges, which would normally be written with an accent. (See https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools#dictionary .)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman please click the link/word for the English usage — plus I believe I got this answer with the same number of doubled letters before the currently accepted answer. It doesn’t appear, from the Wikipedia article, that it is a proper noun either.

Comment: This is why I wish we were allowed more than one check-marked answer - we've also got a new contender that managed 6 letters with no doubling, though the words grow increasingly obscure.  Not quite sure where to draw the line...

Answer (score 6):

For these kinds of questions where "Scrabble dictionary rules" always top out at 5 or 6 characters, I always wish we *would* allow "crossword dictionary rules." For example:

(6 letters, all kinds of cheats)

> ANOLES /
>  NO SALE /
>  ON SALE /
>  [LANOSE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lanose) /
>  E-LOANS /
>  [SLOANE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferris_Bueller%27s_Day_Off#Cast)

(6 letters, 20% proper nouns)

> ENTERS /
>  NESTER /
>  TENSER /
>  RESENT /
>  [STERNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurence_Sterne)

(5 letters, 40% cheats)

> APRES /
>  PEARS /
>  [EARPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Porter_Earp#Descendants) /
>  REAPS /
>  SPARE

(6 letters, 80% proper nouns)

> [EISNER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Eisner) /
>  [IRENES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irene#People) /
>  [SERINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serine) /
>  [NEREIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nereis) /
>  [RIESEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesen)

To justify my posting as an answer, here's one with some uncommon words that hasn't been listed yet. (6 letters, no cheats)

> ALERTS /
>  [LASTER](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/laster#English) /
>  [ESTRAL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/estral) /
>  [RATELS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_badger) /
>  [TALERS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaler) /
>  STALER

Comment: I don't know, judges?  That last one looks plausible, (though the others are clearly bending the rules a bit).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Talers, the link says Thalers. And that Taler became an alternate german word, but it did not affect the english spelling. So it doesn't quite count. Good try though!!!

Comment: @Sensoray: "Taler" is a [Scrabble-accepted](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools#dictionary) historical variant of "Thaler" — as is, for that matter, "Dollar"! https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taler#Etymology_2 I just figured the Wikipedia link would be most relevant to the casual what's-thatter.

Answer (score 5):

**6 words, 5 letters**

> **TONES 
>  STONE 
>  STENO 
>  ONSET 
>  NOTES 
>  SETON**

Comment: dentries for your new solution... :)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Dentries? Do you mean "dendrites" perhaps?

Comment: You've missed the rule that every letter has to appear at the beginning of at least one of the words, though these are certainly honorable mentions, if not complete solutions.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman oh yes, woops. Eh well. Thanks! :)