# Anagram holiday

Tags: word, wordplay, anagram

> Virtues, we devour and restore, usher a puzzle.

Related to the above sentence, find a six-letter word, which anagrams to gives words starting with each of the five different letters of the word.

Comment: Ah, this is what somebody was referring to in the comments for the [one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81384/fully-firstable-anagram-sets) I put up last night.  Great minds, I guess?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, I was inspired by your question to post this - credit is due to you!

Comment: one line wonder...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Given the title, I'm gonna go with ...

> EASTER

Which anagrams to 5 words that (a) start with the different letters of the base word, and (b) are synonyms of words of your sentence.

> [Arete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arete)s (Virtues), Eaters (devours), Reseat (Restore), Seater (Usher), Teaser (Puzzle).