# Series of interestingly increasing words!

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers, word-property

What is the next word(more than one is possible!) in the below sequence of words:

NO, ATE, OPTS,  _ _ _ _ _ ?

Note:

*1*  Only standard English words(as per Oxford English Dictionary) are to be provided.

*2* As multiple answers are possible, first correct entry wins

*3* There can be other sets of words(which are altogether different from the above)- which can form such a sequence. This is /may not be the *only one*

*4* Based on David R's answer, this is getting added: All the letters of the words are different OR there is no repeated letter in any of the words.

Comment: rot13(Vf gurer fbzrguvat havdhr nobhg gur yrggref, engure guna gur jbeqf gurl sbez?)

Comment: I'm not sure I get clue 4: There are two 'O's and two 'T's already...

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman In each word, individually, there are no repeated letters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess:

> ITEMS

Reasoning:

> ITEMS -> ITEMS, TIMES, EMITS, MITES, SMITE (each letter begins its own anagram).

Comment: Yes, you got it correct, well done!

Comment: Hmm, I should've gotten this, since I posted almost the [exact same puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81384/fully-firstable-anagram-sets) six months ago...

Answer (score 15):

I think that it could be

> PARSE (or any anagram thereof)

Reasoning

> I think the $n$th term in the sequence is a word with $n$ letters which has the maximal number of anagrams so PARSE has APERS, APRES, ASPER, PARES, PEARS, PRASE, PRESA, RAPES, REAPS, SPARE, SPEAR (12 anagrams which I think is the most possible for 5 letters).

Comment: Well, hexomino, a good try, though intended answer is different. RAPERS is not possible.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Sorry that was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: I guess the answer should be the lexicographically smallest one.

Answer (score 6):

I think the next word is

> Queue

Because

> Each word has only one vowel or consonant, alternating each word.  NO is 1 of each, ATE is one consonant, OPTS is one vowel, and QUEUE is again one consonant.

Other options in English are

> AUDIO, AERIE, and EERIE

With this logic, the 6 letter word could be

> SNITCH and SPRING with possible entries for THIRTY, TWENTY, and SYSTEM, depending on whether or not you count the Y.

No 7 letter words follow this rule though.

Comment: interesting answer, not the intended answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer could be

> Stare, or its other 4 anagrams: tears, rates, stear (old timey synonym of steer, as in, to stear a car) and earst (which means long ago).

Reason:

> No has two anagrams: on, no, and two letters.
>  Ate has three anagrams: tea, eat, ate, and three letters. 
>  Opts has four anagrams: pots, stop, opts, tops, and 4 letters. 
>  Therefore the next must have five anagrams and five letters.

Comment: rot13("bcgf" unf gjb zber nantenzf: "cbfg" naq "fcbg".  Vg vf cebonoyl gur zbfg nantenznoyr frg bs 4 yrggref.)

Comment: @GridAlien: Yes, you are almost there, but missed by one word, that starts with E. Erst is a correct word, while earst is not, I am afraid. Nice try!